# Android Viewpager OutOfMemoryError Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager

where each page is a fragment with a different image set as a background. Since i need to ensure it scrolls smoothly without lag, i have set the offscreenpage to 20(the number of items in the viewpager)but i am getting this error quite oftenly:

```
   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

i have already compressed the images to the maximum(Compressed JPEGS),any idea how i can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice article in the Training section of the Android developers site: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html... it shows you how to use caching mechanisms in you android applications. You can adopt this in your `ViewPager` implementation.

Comment: how can i use these with fragments?

Comment: Sure... your fragment has a view, with a background (sorry for being captain ;) ). In the adapter you have to set this to the fragments view.

Answer (score 0):

I would load/unload the background images dynamically as you switch fragments. They should load fast enough to not notice, especially if you use an animation to hide the transition (fade in/fade out). Or better yet, load 4 or 5 of them (2 in each direction) so you only see the fading if you scroll very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The bitmap size depends on the pixel density of the image. Try to reduce your background image MPx.